# Parse XML in iPhone (attributed not separated)

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

Is there a way to parse an XML in iOS where the attribute are not separated
e.g:


   `Users

      UserId="1" Name="John Smith" Loc="London"

      UserId="2" Name="Johnny Cash" Loc="Nashville"

   Users`

Thanks

Comment: I have looked at alot of the example but in it the xml elements are separated in this case they are not. In this case the UserId Name and Loc are on one line.

Comment: tried json like iApple suggested??? can you post a little of ur xml here so we cold see how exactly it looks like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seams like you havent got xml at all.  You are missing all usefully symbols that would normally help with the parsing. You taks is to parse a new format specification.

My first bit of advice is to ask whoever is providing you with this feed to put it into a proper format (JSON or plist are the easiest to work with).

Failing this, if the feed is not too big (otherwise you will hit performance issues), parse the feed manually character by character.  You probably want to write a event based parser.

Split the feed line by line, perhaps using [componentsSeparatedByString:](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/componentsSeparatedByString%3a)
Then read characters into a string untill you hit an `=` that string is your key.  Next read between the quotes `""` That string is your value.  FIre the key and the value off to a delegate.

Comment: Yeah I sort of figured that out. I now have the XML fix. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

JSON parsing classes will help you out...

```
    NSString *responseString = @""; // your data contained string.
    SBJSON *json = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];
    NSArray *resultData = [json objectWithString:responseString error:&error];
```